# Pasar valor de campo de texto a variable php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, variables-globales

Como podria pasar el valor de una campo de texto a una  variable php sin  enviar  desde una formulación no tengo mucho conosimiento en ajax  por no decir nada

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Has investigado algo? Aquí mismo hay ya [varias preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax+php) donde se  indica cómo hacer lo que quieres. Tu pregunta no se adapta al formato del sitio, porque no parte de un problema real basado en un código concreto y puede que sea cerrada.

Comment: En realidad si  pero no he encontrado lo que busco

Comment: Me extraña. Parece que no has buscado bien. Yo mismo he respondido al menos a tres o cuatro preguntas muy similares a la tuya. Busca, [aquí tienes la relación de preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax+php)  sobre `ajax`  y sobre `php`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No puedo comentar porque aun no tengo la reputación necesaria. Pero puedes leer la documentación de [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). Es la forma más sencilla de hacer peticiones ajax. Un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer seria.

```
axios.post(
                tu_url,
                {
                    nombre_de_tu_input: valor_de_tu_input
                }
                ).then(
                    res=>{
                        // respuesta 200
                        console.log(res)
                    }, 
                    err=>{
                        // respuesta diferente de 200
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                );
```